# INSERT INTO WITH SELECT and WHERE (Problem)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, where-clause

I need to perform an insert into with select, but DBEAVER is returning the following error:

> SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904:" NR_CARTEIRA ": invalid identifier

Does anyone know what can it be ?

````
INSERT INTO recem_nascido(
   DT_ATENDIMENTO ,
   CD_DECLARACAO_NASCIDO_VIVO,
   cd_atendimento,
   CD_MULTI_EMPRESA,
   cd_paciente,
   nm_paciente,
   CD_ATENDIMENTO_PAI,
   dt_nascimento,
   nm_mae,
   cd_convenio,
   NR_CARTEIRA )
SELECT
   a.DT_ATENDIMENTO ,
   c.CD_DECLARACAO_NASCIDO_VIVO,
   a.cd_atendimento,
   a.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA,
   a.cd_paciente,
   b.nm_paciente,
   a.CD_ATENDIMENTO_PAI,
   b.dt_nascimento,
   b.nm_mae,
   a.cd_convenio,
   a.NR_CARTEIRA
FROM
     DBAMV.ATENDIME a,
     dbamv.paciente b,
     dbamv.recem_nascido c
WHERE 
   a.CD_ATENDIMENTO = 33079344
   AND c.CD_DECLARACAO_NASCIDO_VIVO = 111
   AND A.NR_CARTEIRA = 321321321
   AND a.cd_atendimento_pai IS NOT NULL 
   AND a.CD_PACIENTE = b.CD_PACIENTE 
   AND c.CD_ATENDIMENTO = a.CD_ATENDIMENTO; ```
````

Comment: Well first guess is that you don't have a column in your target table named `NR_CARTEIRA`.

Comment: **Bad habits to kick**: [using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: And along with `JOIN`, learn to use **meaningful** table aliases.  The queries are much easier to read with table abbreviations rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: And it will take probably **next 30 years**  than the *new-style* syntax can be used [safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66403519/4808122) [everywhere](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/ansi-bug/)

Answer (score 0):

There are only two options:

1. The target table `recem_nascido` has no column `NR_CARTEIRA`
2. The table `DBAMV.ATENDIME` has no column `NR_CARTEIRA`

Since you only posted the query, but not the table structure, there is no way to narrow this down further.